# read -p returns "read: no query process" using korn shell ksh

Tags: linux, ksh

created a simple shell file that contains this:

```
read -p ThePrompt TheSomthing
echo $TheSomething
```

Run it, and it returns

```
-ksh[1]: read: no query process
```

I've tried single quotes, double quotes around ThePrompt and the man page specifically says "-p" is to use a prompt but it is not working for me.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: The syntax you give is for bash, not korn shell.

Comment: Yes, I notice that now.  I posted my work around, which is all I need I guess.  Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 4):

In Ksh you can use this format:

`echo "ThePrompt\c"
read TheSomthing
echo $TheSomething`

Answer (score 2):

From the googled [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ksh):

> The -un and -p options cause input to be read from file descriptor n or the current co-process (see Co-Processes above for comments on this), respectively. If the -s option is used, input is saved to the history file.

To use a prompt, write this instead:

```
read TheSomething?'ThePrompt'
```

Comment: What is the ? doing in this case. I'm having a difficult issue Googling an answer.

Comment: @RussPetersen Please read the man page. I updated the link in the answer with a working one which I just Googled, though you could have done the same yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I found a word around:

echo -n 'prompt: '
read input1
echo -n 'prompt: '
read input2
.
.
.

I don't know why the -p doesn't work as described in the man page.  If anyone out there has insights, please reply.

Thanks!

Comment: The correct syntax for `read` in ksh is given by @abacabadabacaba.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for reviving this question, but I do my shell scripts in KSH, so I was in the same predicament, until I came with this.

My solution to capture a single character:

```
$> echo -e "My prompt: \c" ; read -n 1 -s -r FOO ; echo -e "\b"
My prompt:
$> echo $FOO
d
$>
```

For a longer string remove the "-n 1" from the read command:

```
$> echo -e "My prompt: \c" ; read -s -r FOO ; echo -e "\b"
My prompt:
$> echo $FOO
this is my entry!!!
$>
```

I hope this is what you were looking for... Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found this post. The odd thing is:
On server A, this syntax works fine
`read -p "Prompt" -e -n 2 answer`
On server B, I get the error:
`-ksh: read: no query process`
Both servers are running Redhat 7.9 and ksh 93. Save version of the RPMs & kernel. Even though this was a ksh script, seems like server A was using the bash version of read. Wierd.

The `-n` option also behaved differently.
On serve A (bash), typing N filled the variable answer with N. Also, it stripped any spaces out of the input.
On server B, typing N filled the variable answer with N\r.

My solution, which works on both servers:
```` read -n 2 answer?'Prompt '```
answer=$( echo $answer | tr -d '[:cntrl:][:blank:]' ) ````

Where the read is the format described by @abacabadabacaba
The tr command deletes `-d` all the control characters `[:cntrl:]` and all the white space `[:blank:]`

#Wierdness